# Add a movie to org-mode html output

Tags: html, emacs, movie, org-mode

In my org file I have a hyperlink to a movie

```
[[mymovie.avi][Click here to watch my movie]]
```

When exporting this to html, this link gets converted to an html-link that I can click on to open a new browser tab, where finally the movie plays.

This is, however, not very convenient. Is there a way to have a youtube-like frame inside the html page that plays that movie, just as it is done for images?

**Edit:** I found that the html object command works, if I replace the link in the html file by it

```
<object data="mymovie.avi" height=300 width=300></object>
```

Can the html export behaviour of .avi files be changed to this?

Comment: You may have better luck asking this on the org-mode mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode . The section of the manual referring to custom hyperlinks (http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html#Adding-hyperlink-types) might work as well, but I'm not certain how you'd then adjust the exporter to deal with the new link type.

Comment: A first work around could be to use verbatim HTML. Any real fix probably needs modifications to the exporter.

Answer (score 0):

Org mode is now part of vanilla Emacs. Consider filing an enhancment request, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (Yes, that is for enhancement requests too, not just bug reports.)